# Why has the Bombardier CSeries been delayed in starting service with Delta Air Lines?

Tags: airline-operations, airlines, aircraft-production, fleet

Delta Air Lines placed a large order for the Bombardier CSeries. I don't know the original projected date for the start of CSeries flying, but I think it already passed.

When is DAL planning to start CSeries flying? What is the reason for the delay? Have any problems with the aircraft itself caused the delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [delta news brief](https://news.delta.com/delta-determining-exact-timing-cs100-aircraft-deliveries-after-full-itc-written-decision) from February of this year alludes to the fact they are waiting for the Alabama production facility to be completed, presumably where they will build the aircraft.

> Delta still intends to take as many deliveries as possible **from the
>   new Airbus/Bombardier facility in Mobile, Alabama, as soon as that
>   facility is up and running.** However, as the ITC notes, the airline has
>   contractual commitments to begin taking deliveries later this year and
>   the ITC decision clears the way for Delta to accept deliveries in
>   Canada as well....
>
> ....and while **pleased that imports from Canada can now be part of the
>   near-term solution, Delta looks forward to taking U.S. manufactured
>   aircraft from Mobile** when that facility opens.​

This [article notes](https://www.flightglobal.com/news/articles/delta-sees-early-2019-debut-for-cseries-447653/) that during an earnings call they mention early 2019 as the projected start of operations for the aircraft. The article also notes they were slated to take 15 aircraft in 2018 but "program delays" prevented this. The article does not detail what those delays were (presumably the lack of the Mobile facility contributed along with the tariff issues).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because the tariff issue has not been resolved.

https://business.financialpost.com/transportation/u-s-upholds-nearly-300-per-cent-tariffs-on-bombardiers-cseries

Comment: This seems like more of a comment than an answer. If you believe it to be an answer, could you reference the "tariff issue" you are talking about?

Comment: The International Trade Commission rejected the 300% tariff in early 2018.

Comment: @MikeCowan Delta isn't going to push it with the current political climate. This [article states](https://www.cbc.ca/news/business/bombardier-boeing-tariffs-1.4505114) "The lone U.S. customer, Delta Air Lines Inc., was originally expected to receive the first of its firm order for 75 CS100 planes in the spring, but now plans to wait until the aircraft are assembled in the United States." Of course, this may not be the whole story.

Comment: Also note.  The airplane is going to be renamed the Airbus A2xx soon.  It's now an Airbus program and is being sealed off from the rest of BA commercial aircraft.  C Series gone, RJ production slowly dying, and they are looking for a buyer for the Q400 program.  Bombardier's long term strategic plan is to get out of the commercial aircraft business and go back to bizjets only.